# Searching Database PHP/MYSQL Question

Tags: php, mysql, search

Right now I'm just using a simple

```
WHERE name LIKE '%$ser%'
```

But I'm running into an issue - say the search is Testing 123 and the "name" is Testing, it's not coming back with any results. Know any way to fix it? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do and why you expect searching for 'testing 123' to give a positive match on the name 'testing'? And when don't you want it to match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to search for 'Testing' or '123' use `OR`:

```
WHERE (name LIKE '%Testing%' OR name LIKE '%123%')
```

Note however that this will be very slow as no index can be used and it may return some results you didn't want (like "4123"). Depending on your needs, using a [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) or an external database indexing product like Lucene might be a better option.

Answer (score 3):

That's how LIKE works - it returns rows that **completely** contain the search string, and, if you use "%" optionally contain something else.

If you want to see if the field is contained in a string, you can do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE  "Testing 123" LIKE CONCAT("%",`name`,"%")
```

Comment: Don't use the CONCAT means - that, like wildcarding the left side of a LIKE, will ensure an index can not be used.

Comment: After reading Mr. Byers' answer, I think I misunderstood this question. My query will find all names that are completely contained within the search term. This is NOT what you want to do if your goal is to find names that partially match one part of the search term OR another part.

Comment: Maybe... but it could equally be that you have understood the question correctly. I have reread the question and I still can't tell what is meant. I think either of our answers could be a correct interpretation. I'm hoping that Belgin Fish will clarify things.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Looks like he's marked you correct. Good work interpreting the question - and answering it.

Answer (score 1):

After the variable $ser is replaced, the query is:

`WHERE name LIKE '%Testing 123%'`

You should build the query separating by words:

`WHERE name LIKE '%$word[1]%$word[2]%'`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that yields the same result.

Comment: Only diff is the string concatenation in PHP - doesn't answer the question

Comment: It's not the same result, due to the % between the words. And it is more exact and efficient than using OR with two likes.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott mentioned, you cannot check to see if the search contains the column value, it works the other way round.
so if `$ser = "testing"` and table has a row `name = testing 123` it will return

For what you're trying to do you'll need to tokenize the search query into terms and perform an OR search with each of them or better still check out `mysql full text search` for a much better approach

Answer (score 1):

not efficient (as your example) but working as you want:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%$ser%' OR '$ser' LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Mark and others, a full text search method may be better if possible.

However, you can split the search string on word boundary and use OR logic—but check for the whole string first, then offer the option to widen the search:

*NOTE: Input sanitization and preparation not shown.*

**1**. Query with:

```
$sql_where = "WHERE name LIKE '%$ser%'";
```

**2.** If zero results are returned, ask user if they would like to query each word individually.

**3.** If user requests an 'each word' search, query with:

```
$sql_where = get_sql_where($ser);
```

(Working) Example Code Below:

```
$ser = 'Testing 123';
$msg = '';

function get_sql_where($ser){
    global $msg;
    $sql_where = '';
    $sql_where_or = '';

    $ser = preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ", trim($ser)); //replace consecutive spaces with single space
    $search_words = explode(" ", $ser);

    if($search_words[0] == ''){
        $msg = 'Search quested was blank.';
    }else{
        $msg = 'Search results for any of the following words:' . implode(', ', $search_words);
        $sql_where = "WHERE name LIKE '%$ser%'";
        foreach($search_words as $word){
            $sql_where_or .= " OR name LIKE '%$word%'";
        }
    }

    return $sql_where . $sql_where_or;
}

$sql_where = get_sql_where($ser);
//Run query using $sql_where string
```